# Getting 504 Gateway Time-out while running SplashRequest through ScrapySpider

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, scrapy, scrapy-splash

**Running ubuntu on VM VirtualBox.**

**Running ifconfig command:**

```
>docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:90ff:fe9b:4d22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:90:9b:4d:22  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10757  bytes 5983236 (5.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10909  bytes 15688953 (15.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::6ec6:7ba3:79fa:8791  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:92:a7:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 145146  bytes 145357306 (145.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 79019  bytes 19069408 (19.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8252  bytes 3265348 (3.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8252  bytes 3265348 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Scrapy Terminal:**

Retrying GET http://www.gari.pk/used-cars-search/via
http://172.17.0.1:8050/execute (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out

**Splash Terminal:**

> 2019-07-24 08:14:07.645051 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
>   libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>   libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>   process 1: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
>   See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
>   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
>   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
>
> 2019-07-24 08:14:40.935910 [events] {
>      "_id":140385374548096,
>      "client_ip":"172.17.0.1",
>      "maxrss":145496,
>      "rendertime":30.157784700393677,
>      "path":"/execute",
>      "status_code":504,
>      "load":[
>         0.23,
>         0.25,
>         0.26
>      ],
>      "error":{
>         "type":"GlobalTimeoutError",
>         "info":{
>            "timeout":30
>         },
>         "description":"Timeout exceeded rendering page",
>         "error":504
>      },
>      "method":"POST",
>      "qsize":0,
>      "args":{
>         "headers":{
>            "Accept-Language":"en",
>            "User-Agent":"Scrapy/1.6.0 (+https://scrapy.org)",
>            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
>         },
>         "url":"http://www.gari.pk/used-cars-search/",
>         "cookies":[  ],
>   "uid":140385374548096,
>     "lua_source":"\n    function find_search_input(inputs)\n        if #inputs == 1 then\n            return inputs[1]\n        else\n            for _, input in ipairs(inputs) do\n                if input.node.attributes.type == \"search\" then\n                    return input\n                end\n            end\n        end\n    end\n\n    function find_input(forms)\n        local potential = {}\n\n        for _, form in ipairs(forms) do\n            local inputs = form.node:querySelectorAll('input:not([type=\"hidden\"])')\n            if #inputs ~= 0 then\n                local input = find_search_input(inputs)\n                if input then\n                    return form, input\n                end\n\n                potential[#potential + 1] = {input=inputs[1], form=form}\n            end\n        end\n\n        return potential[1].form, potential[1].input\n    end\n\n    function main(splash, args)\n        -- find a form and submit \"splash\" to it\n        local function search_for_splash()\n        local forms = splash:select_all('form')\n\n        if #forms == 0 then\n            error('no search form is found')\n        end\n\n        local form, input = find_input(forms)\n\n        if not input then\n            error('no search form is found')\n        end\n\n        assert(input:send_keys('honda'))\n        assert(splash:wait(0))\n        assert(form:submit())\n    end\n\n    -- main rendering script\n    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))\n    assert(splash:wait(5))\n    search_for_splash()\n    assert(splash:wait(15))\n    --assert(splash:runjs('search_query('', (100));'))\n    local button = splash:select('a[href*=\"search_query\"]')\n    button.node:setAttribute('href', \"javascript: search_query('', (20))\");\n    button:mouse_click()\n    assert(splash:wait(120))\n  \n    return {html = splash:html()}\n    end\n    "
>    },
>      "timestamp":1563956080,
>      "fds":21,
>      "active":0,
>      "user-agent":"Scrapy/1.6.0 (+https://scrapy.org)"
>   }
>   2019-07-24 08:14:40.936842 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [24/Jul/2019:08:14:40 +0000] "POST /execute HTTP/1.1" 504 119 "-" "Scrapy/1.6.0 (+https://scrapy.org)"

**Tried this:** docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 240

**garispider.py**

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class GarispiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gariSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.gari.pk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.gari.pk/used-cars-search/']
    lua_script = """
    function find_search_input(inputs)
        if #inputs == 1 then
            return inputs[1]
        else
            for _, input in ipairs(inputs) do
                if input.node.attributes.type == "search" then
                    return input
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function find_input(forms)
        local potential = {}

        for _, form in ipairs(forms) do
            local inputs =        form.node:querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"])')
            if #inputs ~= 0 then
                local input = find_search_input(inputs)
                if input then
                    return form, input
                end

                potential[#potential + 1] = {input=inputs[1], form=form}
            end
        end

        return potential[1].form, potential[1].input
    end

    function main(splash, args)
        -- find a form and submit "splash" to it
        local function search_for_splash()
        local forms = splash:select_all('form')

        if #forms == 0 then
            error('no search form is found')
        end

        local form, input = find_input(forms)

        if not input then
            error('no search form is found')
        end

        assert(input:send_keys('honda'))
        assert(splash:wait(0))
        assert(form:submit())
    end

    -- main rendering script
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(5))
    search_for_splash()
    assert(splash:wait(15))
    --assert(splash:runjs('search_query('', (100));'))
    local button = splash:select('a[href*="search_query"]')
    button.node:setAttribute('href', "javascript: search_query('', (20))");
    button:mouse_click()
    assert(splash:wait(120))

    return {html = splash:html()}
    end
    """


    def start_requests(self):
        url=self.start_urls[0]
        yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.lua_script})

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.body)
###########################################################################

############################Setting.py#####################################
BOT_NAME = 'ScrappyApp'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ScrappyApp.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ScrappyApp.spiders'
# SPLASH_URL = 'http://10.0.2.15:8050'
SPLASH_URL = 'http://172.17.0.1:8050'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}


SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False


ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'ScrappyApp.pipelines.ScrappyappPipeline': 300,
}
```

I expect body of the html after the lua script. But getting 
Retrying http://www.gari.pk/used-cars-search/ via http://172.17.0.1:8050/execute> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: Why do you use Splash to make form request? Scrapy has ForRequest it should work

Comment: Because need to click a button after searching for a keyword, and am a beginner with scrapy need learn working with splash.

Comment: You can make POST request on URL in the form with word that you try to find. This url is following http://www.gari.pk/used-cars-search/

Comment: The site is using Js to load the search results that's why I need to run a lua_script through SplashRequest.

Comment: You can emulate this behavior by AJAX request, pls check my answer. It will work in Scrapy too.

Comment: What is your relationship to the domain you are testing? It has figured in spam again recently.

Answer (score 0):

Have no prepared project with Scrapy. I will show you an example with `requests` but it can be easily converted into Scrapy request

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://www.gari.pk/search-car-ajax.php', {'search_param': 'cars_mini/,/c_date desc/bmw'})
```

In `r.content` you will have a response with data that you are looking for. The for paginations, the site makes the same request but add some offset, everything that you should do is to add this offset into data. Here is an example

```
r = requests.post('http://www.gari.pk/search-car-ajax.php', {'search_param': 'cars_mini/,/c_date desc/bmw/10'})
```

As you can see it add 10 `{'search_param': 'cars_mini/,/c_date desc/bmw/10'}`
Maybe you can take more result per request.
I would recommend you check Developerconcole->network->Xhr
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest('http://www.gari.pk/search-car-ajax.php', callback=self.parse,method='POST', formdata={'search_param': 'cars_mini/,/c_date desc/bmw/10'})
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I need a solution with splash as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the url that you want to scrapy returns `transfer-encoding` header. I opened a issue about this on [Github](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/932).

Here the script to proof that (url httpbin.org/headers) returns the same headers i sent on request.

```
import requests
import json

ENDPOINT_SPLASH = 'http://localhost:8050/execute'


def test_with_custom_headers():
    lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
     splash:set_custom_headers({
       ["x-custom-header"] = "splash"
     })
     assert(splash:go(args.url))
     assert(splash:wait(0.5))
     return {
       html = splash:html()
     }
    end
    """

    payload = {
        'lua_source': lua_script,
        'url': 'https://httpbin.org/headers',
        'timeout': 15,
    }

    r = requests.post(url=ENDPOINT_SPLASH,
                      json=payload)

    result = json.loads(r.text)

    return result.get('html', result)


def test_with_content_encoding():
    lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
     splash:set_custom_headers({
       ["transfer-encoding"] = "chunked"
     })
     assert(splash:go(args.url))
     assert(splash:wait(0.5))
     return {
       html = splash:html()
     }
    end
    """

    payload = {
        'lua_source': lua_script,
        'url': 'https://httpbin.org/headers',
        'timeout': 15,
    }

    r = requests.post(url=ENDPOINT_SPLASH,
                      json=payload)

    result = json.loads(r.text)

    return result.get('html', result)


print("test_with_custom_headers: \n{}\n".format(test_with_custom_headers()))
print("test_with_content_encoding: \n{}".format(test_with_content_encoding()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Gaspar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9291099/gaspar), It worked, when I unable to handle 504 Gateway timeout errors using splashRequest. And splashRequest don't hand timeout properly. Do you have any idea on how to handle timeout using splashRequest? I used below one and I got timeout after 30 secs.

```
yield SplashRequest(url,self.after_login,method="GET",endpoint="execute",args={'lua_source': script},splash_headers={"Connection":"keep-alive"},)
```

settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 
 810,
}
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 600
```

EDIT!!!

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url,
                            self.parse,
                            args={'wait': 0.5, 'viewport': '1024x2480', 'timeout': 90, 'images': 0, 'resource_timeout': 10},
                            )
```

This worked for me.